# Error in Karma/Jasmine Unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

This is my AngularJS code:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
        $scope.name = "Girish";
        $scope.sayHello = function() {
            $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
        };
        $scope.commonUrl = "/";
        $rootScope.$watch('eng', function() {
            $scope.currentLang = $rootScope.CURRENT_LANGUAGE;
        });
        $scope.homePageFirstSlider = function() {
            $scope.anun = "Nar";
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: "/" + "eng" + '/api/getslideritems/main'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.Data = response.data;
                    $scope.loadCss('mainCarousel');
                },
                function errorCallback(response) {});
        };
    });
```

This is a test file:

```
'use strict';
describe('myapp', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myapp'));
    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    describe('$scope.sayHello', function() {
        it('same tests', function() {
            var $scope = {};
            var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
            $scope.name = 'Girish';
            $scope.sayHello();
            expect($scope.greeting).toEqual('Hello Girish');
        });
    });
});
```

After I run karma.conf.js  file I have this error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) myapp $scope.sayHello same tests FAILED
    ***Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams <- MainCtrl***
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams%20%3C-%20MainCtrl in /var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js (line 4397)

    loaded@http://localhost:9882/context.js:151:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.025 secs / 0.004 secs)
Chromium 45.0.2454 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.008 secs / 0.005 secs)
```

How can I solve this error?

> Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams <- MainCtrl

Answer (score 0):

`$routeParams` service is a part of `ngRoute` module. So you'll have to include it as a dependency on your module.

Here's how:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])
```

Also you should be mocking the controller in the first `beforeEach` block instead of mocking it inside a specific test, so that it could be reusable in all your tests.

And your tests will still be failing because you've inject an empty object for `$scope` instead of creating a new scope using the `$rootScope`'s `$new` function. So you should be doing the following changes to make them pass:

```
describe('myapp', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myapp'));

    //Replace this
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_){
    //With this
    // beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$routeParams_, _$http_){

        //Uncomment the following comments if needed for writing tests for the $watch function.
        // $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        // $http = _$http_;
        // $routeParams = _$routeParams_;
        controller = $controller('MainCtrl', { 
            $scope: $scope,
            // $http: $http,
            // $rootScope: $rootScope,
            // $routeParams: $routeParams
        });
    }));

    describe('$scope.sayHello', function() {
        it('same tests', function() {
            $scope.name = 'Girish';
            $scope.sayHello();
            expect($scope.greeting).toEqual('Hello Girish');
        });
    });
});
```